# What does $U^{-N}$ means? Where N is the natural numbers set.

Tags: set-theory

I was reading this paper called;
"The echo state approach to analysing and training recurrent neural networks-with an erratum note."

In the paper, I found the expression: $\left(u(n)\right)_{n\in J} \in U^{J}$, where $U$ and $J$ are sets. There is also this other expression $u(n) \in U^{-\mathbb{N}}$. Both expressions are in page $6$. I don't understand what $U^{J}$ and $U^{-\mathbb{N}}$ means. I don't know much of set theory, sorry for any rookie mistakes. Can someone explain these to me?

Comment: quite possibly $u(\cdot):J \to U$. Sometimes $U^J$ indicates all possible functions from J into U

Comment: @311411 That looks right to me.  And $-\mathbb N$ seems to just mean the negative integers, i.e. the case of left-infinite sequences.

Comment: @ErickWong using $- \mathbb{N} $ instead of $\mathbb{Z}^-$ to represent negative numbers is correct?

Comment: @RafaelSantiago94 It's not unheard of (e.g. it's analogous to using $2\mathbb N$ for even positive integers), so it's "correct" in the sense that authors have substantial leeway to use whatever notation they want, so long as it broadly understandable.